# WordPress shortcode to display related posts

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, post

WordPress shortcode to display related posts

How To Display Related Posts in WordPress Manually

This is my code:

```
function related_posts_shortcode( $atts ) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'limit' => '5',
), $atts));

global $wpdb, $post, $table_prefix;

if ($post->ID) {
    $retval = '<ul>';
    // Get tags
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
    $tagsarray = array();
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tagsarray[] = $tag->term_id;
    }
    $tagslist = implode(',', $tagsarray);

    // Do the query
    $q = "SELECT p.*, count(tr.object_id) as count
        FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt, $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr, $wpdb->posts AS p WHERE tt.taxonomy ='post_tag' AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tr.object_id  = p.ID AND tt.term_id IN ($tagslist) AND p.ID != $post->ID
            AND p.post_status = 'publish'
            AND p.post_date_gmt < NOW()
        GROUP BY tr.object_id
        ORDER BY count DESC, p.post_date_gmt DESC
        LIMIT $limit;";

    $related = $wpdb->get_results($q);
    if ( $related ) {
        foreach($related as $r) {
            $retval .= '
<li><a title="'.wptexturize($r->post_title).'" href="'.get_permalink($r->ID).'">'.wptexturize($r->post_title).'</a></li>';  
   }
    } else {
        $retval .= '<li>No related posts found</li>';
    }
    $retval .= '</ul>
  ';
    return $retval;
    }
    return;
 }
 add_shortcode('related_posts', 'related_posts_shortcode');
```

It does not work as I would like. What I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  Class WP Query to get custom loop
[wp query class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

```
// Create Shortcode related_posts_
// Shortcode: [related_posts_ number="5"]
function create_relatedposts_shortcode($atts) {

        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
               'number' => '5',
            ), $atts, 'related_posts_'
        );

        // Custom WP query relatedposts
        $args_relatedposts = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $atts['number'],
            'order' => 'DESC',
        );

        $relatedposts = new WP_Query( $args_relatedposts );

        if ( $relatedposts->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $relatedposts->have_posts() ) {
                $relatedposts->the_post();
                // add here your html for post 
            }
        } else {
            // not found post 
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

}
add_shortcode( 'related_posts_', 'create_relatedposts_shortcode' );
```