# How to show related posts in two columns

Tags: wordpress

I want to show related posts in two columns at the end of the post. My blog is [techbyet.com](https://techbyet.com)

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question.  Here is a good place to start - [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for related posts https://wordpress.org/plugins/related-post/

Or

If you can add your own code so you need to follow this link: [WordPress shortcode to display related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385584/wordpress-shortcode-to-display-related-posts)